# Multiple cursor selection on a pattern in Visual Studio Code

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a similar way that I work in Sublime Text:

Find All for a specific regular expression. Then it has multiple-selected the texts I need.

A simple find and replace does not fulfil my needs. I need to move the cursors to some segment in the lines to edit.

I m on Windows.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Windows & Linux

Per an answer to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode):

- Do a normal Find ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ) using regular expressions.

[image: Visual Studio Code RegEx Find]

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all the Find matches. This will insert multiple cursors at the end of each occurrence.
- Use the Left Arrow <kbd>◄</kbd> and Right Arrow <kbd>►</kbd> keys to move the synced cursors within each selection.
- Edit selections as necessary.

[Official Keyboard Shortcut List For Visual Studio Code On Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)
[Official Keyboard Shortcut List For Visual Studio Code On Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)

---

### macOS

- Do a normal Find ( <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ) using regular expressions.
- Press <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all the Find matches. This will insert multiple cursors at the end of each occurrence.

[Official Keyboard Shortcut List For Visual Studio Code On macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much this saved lot of my time

Comment: @MaheshJamdade You're welcome. Glad to know you found it helpful. =)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @SunitGautam You are very welcome. =)

Comment: Additionally, if you need to confine the search to a region of the file, make a selection, then hit the "bars" icon near the right of the search field to activate "Find in Selection".